# Preserving trailing characters when using sed to replace variable data

Tags: regex, bash, sed

If I have a string like:

```
p1 and p11 are going to visit p111. p1 is the father of p111
```

How could I use sed (or anything, really) to replace each instance of p{n} with a different value? So that the result would be something like:

```
Bob and Jane are going to visit Paul. Bob is the father of Paul
```

Basically, I'm looking for a way to tell sed, "Find exactly p{n} followed by anything other than a number, and replace it with $var, but don't replace the thing that follows {n}."

If I do something simple like

```
text="p1 and p11 are going to visit p111. p1 is the father of p111"
text=`echo "$text" | sed s/p1/Bob/g`
```

I end up replacing every occurrence of "p1" with "Bob," and no subsequent substitutions can take place:

Bob and Bob1 are going to visit Bob11. Bob is the father of Bob11

The closest I've come is something like

```
text=`echo "$text" | sed 's/p1[^0-9]/bob/g'`
```

This has two problems: It consumes the trailing character (space, punctuation), and it doesn't match p{n} at the end of a line. After looping through everything that needs to be replaced:

Boband Janeare going to visit Paul Bobis the father of p111

Anyone have an idea how I can find what I need to replace, not insert into other variables, and not consume the trailing non-digit character?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not first replace `p111`, then `p11`, then `p1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  The trick is to preserve anything that you do not want to lose using matched groups, delimited by escaped parentheses, and brought into the replacement string using backreferences `\1`, `\2`, ..., `\9`:

```
s/p1\([^0-9]\)/Bob\1/g
```

There is also an alternative method, [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), that may or may not be available in your version of `sed`, and if it is, requires enabling its "perl mode" of regex syntax.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble getting this to work for me, but Google tells me this is the approach I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeMitchell - If the regex is directly part of the command line, you need to escape the backslashes which means typing them twice each.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple file containing the desired replacements, call it `data`:

```
1 Bob
11 Jane
111 Paul
```

then read it using awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ while( getline d < "data" ) { split(d,a); r[a[1]]=a[2]}}
  { for( i in r ) gsub( "p"i, r[i])}1' input
```

Note that this may or may not work as is, depending on how the array is built.  In my implementation, the iteration of r works because the order returned happens to be '111', '11', '1', but that is certainly not well defined behavior.  You can force the desired ordering of the replacements by reading the data file each time instead of reading it into an array:

```
awk '{
  while( getline d < "data" ) { 
    split( d,a ); 
    gsub( "p"a[1],a[2])
  }
  close("data")}1' input
```

This requires that you be careful in the construction of the lookup file, and in this case requires that the lines of data be the reverse of those given above.  If you prefer to add a word delimiter, it is probably easier to use perl:

```
use autodie;
open my $f, "<", "data";
while(<$f>) {@a = split; $n{$a[0]} = $a[1]}
while(<>) {
  foreach $i (keys %n ) { s/p$i(\W)/$n{$i}$1/g }
  print
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
sed s/p1\\b/Bob/g
```

\b is a zero-width assertion standing for word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

A one liner calling sed 3 times, replacing p111,p11,p1 in reverse order.

```
echo "grep p1 and p11 are going to visit p111. p1 is the father of p111"|sed 's/p111/Paul/g'|sed 's/p11/Jane/g'|sed 's/p1/Bob/g'
```